# Submit button not rendering on a dynamic form with tables

Tags: 8, forms

I want to display a dynamic with table field
when I click add button, it should add new line of form, also i can't display the add button
So how can I resolve this mistakes ?

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $this->connection = Database::getConnection();
  $connection = Database::getConnection();
  $req = "SELECT id, name FROM details_types_sejours_field_data;";
  $reponse = $connection->query($req);
  $results = $reponse->fetchAll();
  $this->liste += [
    '0' => t('Choose'),
  ];
  foreach ($results as $result){
    $this->liste += [
      $result->id => $result->name,
    ];
  }
  $header = array();
  $header['journee'] = $this->t('Stays days');
  $header['matin'] = $this->t('Morning');
  $header['soir'] = $this->t('Evening');
  $header['observations'] = $this->t('Comments');  

  $config = $this->config('monmodule.homepage');
  $pomoted_items = $config->get('promoted', []);
  $number_promoted = $form_state->getValue('number_promoted', count($pomoted_items));
  $removed = $form_state->getValue('removed_promoted', []);

  $form['number_promoted'] = [
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $number_promoted,
  ];
  $form['removed'] = [
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $removed,
  ];
  $form['promoted'] = array(
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#title' => t("Days number"),
    //'#size' => '14',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_promoted; $i++) {
    $item = array_shift($pomoted_items);
    if (in_array($i, $removed)) {
      continue;
    }
    $form['promoted'][$i] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      //'#header' => $header,
      '#title' => t("Day number #@i", ['@i' => $i]),
    ];

    $form['promoted'][$i] = [
      'journee' => array(
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#title' => $this->t('Stays'),
        '#default_value' => $item['title'],
      ),
      // Matin

      'matin' => array(
         array(
          '#type' => 'datetime',
          '#title' => $this->t("Start hour"),
          '#default_value' => $item['title'],
        ),
        array(
          '#type' => 'datetime',
          '#title' => $this->t("End hour"),
          '#default_value' => $item['title'],
        ),
        array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#default_value' => 'Choose',
          '#options' => $this->liste,
          '#title' => $this->t('Requested service:'),
        )
      ),


      'soir'=>array(
        array(
          '#type' => 'datetime',
          '#title' => $this->t("Start hour"),
          '#default_value' => $item['title'],
        ),
        array(
          '#type' => 'datetime',
          '#title' => $this->t("End hour"),
          '#default_value' => $item['title'],
        ),
        array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#default_value' => 'Choose',
          '#options' => $this->liste,
          '#title' => $this->t('Requested service:'),
        )
      ),

      'observations' => array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => $this->t('Comments:'),
        '#cols' => '20',
        '#rows' => '5',
      ),
    ];

    /*
    // Observations
    $form['promoted'][$i]['observations'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('Comments'),
      '#rows' => 5,
      '#cols' => 20,
      '#resizable' => TRUE,
    ];
    */

    $form['promoted']['remove_' . $i][$i] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t("Supprimer l'élément #@i", ['@i' => $i]),
      '#submit' => ['::removeItem'],
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['button--danger'],
        'data-toRemove' => $i,
      ]
    ];
  }

  $form['promoted']['add_item'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Ajouter un autre élément'),
    '#submit' => ['::addPromotedItem'],
  ];

  return $form;
}

public function addPromotedItem(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setValue('number_promoted', $form_state->getValue('number_promoted') + 1);
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}

public function removeItem(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $removed = $form_state->getValue('removed_promoted', []);
  $removed[] = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#attributes']['data-toRemove'];
  $form_state->setValue('removed_promoted', $removed);
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

[image]

Comment: `t()` calls should be avoided in classes, use `$this->t()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are following the Example module's [`AjaxAddMore.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_api_example%21src%21Form%21AjaxAddMore.php/8.x-1.x) example (click: View source).

I also guess Form API is a little bit picky when it comes to element nesting. So please simply try to put the submit in the `$form['actions']` container as in the example or alternatively put it just on the top level.

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
];
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but when I click to delete a line of table it deletes only one line !!!

Comment: @GhanmiKais – Seems logical to me...